# Self-referencing reactive variables in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, recursion, shiny, reactive-programming

I am building a shiny app that periodically reads new data, then uses that data and a previous parameter estimate to produce a new parameter estimate (and so on ad infinitum).

The issue is that the parameter must by reactive to update when the data updates, but also needs to reference its previous value, I am not sure how to use its current value to calculate its next value without shiny complaining about infinite recursion. A minimal example is below, it is intended to print a value that increments itself by 1 every second.

```
library(shiny)

omega <- 0

# Define the UI
myui <- basicPage(  
    textOutput('var')
)

# Define the server code
myserver <- function(input, output, session) {

    omega <<- reactive({
        invalidateLater(1000, NULL)
        return(omega() + 1)
    })

    output$var <- renderText(omega())
}


# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = myui, server = myserver)
```

This produces the following error

```
evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

If I try to protect the call to omega() within omega by using isolate() I get a segfault from a C stack overflow.

Is there a way to fix this? Or perhaps a better way to do what I want within shiny?

Comment: `segfault` usually occurs when you are trying to access the memory which isn't meant for you. Your `omega()` is poorly constructed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to the problem but does not exactly address the question.

```
library(shiny)

omega_nr <- 0

# Define the UI
myui <- basicPage(  
  textOutput('var')
)

# Define the server code
myserver <- function(input, output, session) {

  omega <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    return(omega_nr)
  })

  # update non reactive value
  observe({
    omega()
    omega_nr<<-omega_nr+1
  })

  output$var <- renderText(omega())
}


# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = myui, server = myserver)
```

This is working I just tested it.

I'll try other options and let you know. Meanwhile I'm also interested in exact solution. But somehow I feel that self referencing reactive should not be implemented. But I may be wrong..

Comment: So every time omega is invalidated, the observe block is executed, which means the new value will be incremented. This is very clear thank you.

If I may suggest an improvement: if one puts `isolate()` around `omega_nr<<-omega_nr+1` then the counter starts at zero (i.e. observe is not called until the first invalidation occurs).

Comment: I guess isolate around `omega_nr<<-omega_nr+1` wil not have any difference as omega_nr is non- reactive. Also I kind of figured out why recursion is not possible [at least straight forward]. I'll put in my next comment/ answer.

Comment: You can't have direct recursion on the functions [reactive] which involves `invalidateLater` as it will be deeply nested and rsession will terminate or it will not run.

Answer (score 3):

You can just build a function that does that:

```
library(shiny)

myui <- basicPage(  textOutput('var'))
myserver <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  omega <<- 0
  update_data <- function(){omega <<- omega + 1}

  output$var <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    update_data()})
})

shinyApp(ui = myui, server = myserver)
```

Comment: This works, thank you. But it is necessary for the original problem for me to keep the `invalidateLater()` expression within the function which will update the data, since that will have several reactive dependencies. Therefore Indranil's solution works better for me.